# How to open http only site in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, ssl-certificate

I am debugging my localhost site at chrome but not able to browse it, Chrome convert `http` into `https` automatically & not able to access it.
I tried & noticed chrome is converting all http site to try to open on https, that is not an issue if you can browse site with https & have valid certificate.

But in my case https is enabled for localhost then also it creates different issue [Your connection is not private NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066709/your-connection-is-not-private-neterr-cert-common-name-invalid) since it doesn't recognize self-signed certificate safe.

I am stuck in debugging for chrome which is used by most users.

Please help.

PS this is happening since last chrome update & I am able to debug on IE & firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I solved it by change the 'localhost' to 127.1.0.0. That means, if your project run on localhost:8000, then you can replace it like - 127.1.0.0:8000. Try this.