# Privacy Error while launching backend WebAPI Project --

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, privacy

I downloaded a sample ecommerce project from - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X6g7ByUiDPHshYQ2BM0GIEiBS0XmJg8x

Ran the scripts for database and it all went well. Then proceeded to load and launch the backend web-api for this project through visualstudio 2022. The webapi project has been written with .netcore 6.0. What I am getting on the browser is the following -

```
    Privacy Error
    
    Your connection is not private
    Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, 
    passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
    NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID
```

What do I need to fix and/or change in order to bypass this glitch and have the api up and running? As I understand this, it's probably asking for some kind of certificate installation? Need some guidance on this one please. I've given the download link as well so that you can see for yourself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions that require information to be downloaded from Google Drive files are usually not good questions for Stack Overflow, and that is true for this question. Questions need to be self-contained, and external links should be used only for elaboration. The odds that the Google Drive in this question will remain valid for a long time are very small.

Comment: hi @PresidentJamesK.Polk

I've posted questions before that contained links to github repo for source code etc. Nobody told me anything then. Maybe SO has updated its list of Do's and Don'ts? anyway, disregarding that link what do you think the response message be pointing towards? WHEN DOES THAT TYPE OF MESSAGE OCCUR AND WHAT EXACTLY NEEDS TO BE DONE? Can you give me an answer to that one??

Comment: Well I just found this and implemented it to my scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066709/your-connection-is-not-private-neterr-cert-common-name-invalid
and it has solved my problem. Although the marked answer in that post has not mentioned anything about exposing any security vulnerabilities.